# Is it OK to change a contact hash in order to invalidate all checksums for that contact?

Tags: checksum, contact-hash

Sometimes, someone makes a mistake and sends out a personalized link in a mailing with their contact id and checksum, which is not great. In the past, I've simply created a duplicate contact and merged the old contact into the new one, with the result that the old contact id is no longer valid — which solves the problem.

But seeing that one can change the contact hash via API4, I wonder if there is any reason not to just change the hash to some other 32-character hexadecimal number, invalidating all checksums for that contact? Or in other words, is the hash used anywhere else beyond just creating and validating checksums?

There is an [invalidate checksums hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_invalidateChecksum/), but that's not really practical for a one off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 98% sure it would be fine to change the hash. Maybe make a note of the original hash just in case.